# Slow Postgres 9.3 queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to figure out if I can speed up two queries on a database storing email messages. Here's the table:

```
\d messages;
                             Table "public.messages"
     Column     |  Type   |                       Modifiers
----------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id             | bigint  | not null default nextval('messages_id_seq'::regclass)
 created        | bigint  |
 updated        | bigint  |
 version        | bigint  |
 threadid       | bigint  |
 userid         | bigint  |
 groupid        | bigint  |
 messageid      | text    |
 date           | bigint  |
 num            | bigint  |
 hasattachments | boolean |
 placeholder    | boolean |
 compressedmsg  | bytea   |
 revcount       | bigint  |
 subject        | text    |
 isreply        | boolean |
 likes          | bytea   |
 isspecial      | boolean |
 pollid         | bigint  |
 username       | text    |
 fullname       | text    |
Indexes:
    "messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_unique_message_messageid" UNIQUE, btree (groupid, messageid)
    "idx_unique_message_num" UNIQUE, btree (groupid, num)
    "idx_group_id" btree (groupid)
    "idx_message_id" btree (messageid)
    "idx_thread_id" btree (threadid)
    "idx_user_id" btree (userid)
```

Output from `SELECT relname, relpages, reltuples::numeric, pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(oid)) FROM pg_class WHERE oid='messages'::regclass;`

is

```
 relname  | relpages | reltuples | pg_size_pretty
----------+----------+-----------+----------------
 messages |  1584913 |   7337880 | 32 GB
```

Some possibly relevant postgres config values:

```
shared_buffers = 1536MB
effective_cache_size = 4608MB
work_mem = 7864kB
maintenance_work_mem = 384MB
```

Here are the explain analyze outputs:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM messages WHERE groupid=1886 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20 offset 4440;
                                                                      QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=479243.63..481402.39 rows=20 width=747) (actual time=14167.374..14167.408 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using messages_pkey on messages  (cost=0.43..19589605.98 rows=181490 width=747) (actual time=14105.172..14167.188 rows=4460 loops=1)
         Filter: (groupid = 1886)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2364949
 Total runtime: 14167.455 ms
(5 rows)
```

The second query:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM messages WHERE groupid=1886 ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 20 offset 4440;
                                                                        QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=538650.72..538650.77 rows=20 width=747) (actual time=671.983..671.992 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=538639.62..539093.34 rows=181490 width=747) (actual time=670.680..671.829 rows=4460 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 7078kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on messages  (cost=7299.11..526731.31 rows=181490 width=747) (actual time=84.975..512.969 rows=200561 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (groupid = 1886)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_unique_message_num  (cost=0.00..7253.73 rows=181490 width=0) (actual time=57.239..57.239 rows=203423 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (groupid = 1886)
 Total runtime: 672.787 ms
(9 rows)
```

This is on an SSD, 8GB Ram instance, load average is usually around 0.15.

I'm definitely no expert. Is this a case of the data just being spread throughout the disk? Is my only solution to use CLUSTER?

One thing I don't understand is why is it using `idx_unique_message_num` as the index for the second query. And why is ordering by ID so much slower?

Comment: How many records have `groupid=1886` ? Maybe adding an index on `(groupid,id)` and on `(groupid,created)` would help

Comment: There are 200,563 rows for groupid=1886.

Comment: Try adding the indices in the comment, as now postgres has to (sort of) sort these 200,000 records, which is slow. The queries without the `OFFSET` would be faster, but with it, the indices should sort the problem

Comment: That did it. Now runtime is between 5ms-10ms. Thank you!

Comment: Follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092627/slow-postgres-9-3-queries-again

Comment: This and the follow-up seem like good candidates for [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are many records with `groupid=1886` (from comment: there are 200,563), to get to records at an OFFSET of a sorted subset of rows, would require sorting (or an equivalent heap algorithm) which is slow.

This could be solved by adding an index. In this case, one on `(groupid,id)` and another on `(groupid,created)`.

From comment: This indeed helped, taking down the runtime to 5ms-10ms.