# Slow Postgres 9.3 Queries, again

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan, explain, postgresql-performance

This is a follow-up to the question at [Slow Postgres 9.3 queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069637/slow-postgres-9-3-queries).

The new indexes definitely help. But what we're seeing is sometimes queries are much slower in practice than when we run EXPLAIN ANALYZE. An example is the following, run on the production database:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM messages WHERE groupid=957 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 31980;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=127361.90..127441.55 rows=20 width=747) (actual time=152.036..152.143 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_groupid_id on messages  (cost=0.43..158780.12 rows=39869 width=747) (actual time=0.080..150.484 rows=32000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (groupid = 957)
 Total runtime: 152.186 ms
(4 rows)
```

With slow query logging turned on, we see instances of this query taking over 2 seconds. We also have `log_lock_waits=true`, and no slow locks are reported around the same time. What could explain the vast difference in execution times?

Comment: When you `explain analyze` you've probably got the data "hot" in cache. In these cases you probably don't, so more I/O is done. Use `explain (buffers, analyze)` to see buffer use.

Comment: What do you need the offset for? If for pagination, read [this](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset). Maybe you can speed up processing by doing things differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT x OFFSET y` generally performs not much faster than `LIMIT x + y`. A large `OFFSET` is *always* comparatively expensive. The suggested index [in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069637/slow-postgres-9-3-queries) helps, but while you cannot get **index-only scans** out of it, Postgres still has to check visibility in the heap (the main relation) for at least `x + y` rows to determine the correct result.

```
SELECT *
FROM   messages
WHERE  groupid = 957
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  20
OFFSET 31980;
```

`CLUSTER` on your index `(groupid,id)` would help to increase locality of data in the heap and reduce the number of data pages to be read per query. Definitely a win. But if all `groupid` are equally likely to be queried, that's not going to remove the bottleneck of too little RAM for cache. If you have concurrent access, consider pg_repack instead of `CLUSTER`:

- [Optimize Postgres timestamp query range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998139/optimize-postgres-timestamp-query-range/14007963#14007963)

Do you actually need all columns returned? (`SELECT *`) A covering index enabling **index-only scans** might help if you only need a few small columns returned. (`autovacuum` must be strong enough to cope with writes to the table, though. Read-only table would be ideal.)

Also, according to your linked question, your table is 32 GB on disk. (Typically a bit more in RAM). The index on `(groupid,id)` adds another 308 MB *at least* (without any bloat):

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(7337880.0 * 44);  -- row count * tuple size
```

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)

You have 8 GB RAM, of which you expect around 4.5 GB to be used for cache (`effective_cache_size = 4608MB`). That's enough to cache the index for repeated use, but not nearly enough to also cache the whole table.

If your query happens to find data pages in cache, it's fast. Else, not so much. Big difference, even with SSD storage (much more with HDD).

Not directly related to this query, but 8 MB of `work_`mem (`work_mem = 7864kB`) seems way to small for your setup. Depending on various other factors I would set this to at least 64MB (unless you have many concurrent queries with sort / hash operations). Like @Craig commented, `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` might tell us more.

The best query plan also depends on value frequencies. If only few rows pass the filter, the result might be empty for certain `groupid` and the query is comparatively fast. If a large portion of the table has to be fetched, a plain sequential scan wins. You need valid table statistics (`autovacuum` again). And possibly a larger statistics target for `groupid`:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

Comment: Oh, and Postgres 9.3 is getting old. Upgrading to 9.6 might help. Among many other things, there have been various improvements for performance with big tables.

Comment: Small note to PG 9.6 - I found pg 9.6.1 needs higher work_mem settings on the same HW than we used previously on pg 9.5. I found it because costs of some queries running very well on 9.5 were suddenly absolutely horrible on 9.6

Answer (score 1):

Since `OFFSET` is slow, an alternative is to simulate `OFFSET` using another column and some index preparation. We require a UNIQUE column (like a PRIMARY KEY) on the table. If there is none, one can be added with:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE messages_pkey_seq ;
ALTER TABLE messages 
  ADD COLUMN message_id integer DEFAULT nextval('messages_pkey_seq');
```

Next we create the `position` column for the `OFFSET` simulation:

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN position INTEGER;
UPDATE messages SET position = q.position FROM (SELECT message_id,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS position
  FROM messages ) AS q WHERE q.message_id=messages.message_id ;
CREATE INDEX ON messages ( group_id, position ) ;
```

Now we are ready for the new version of the query in the OP:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE group_id = 957 AND
  position BETWEEN 31980 AND (31980+20-1) ;
```

Comment: On the down side, this method is good for read-only tables only, or the `position` column needs to be recalculated after changes to work correctly